# Proof of a exercise problem from basic set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone have a quick check of my answer. The textbook solution is very conversational, and it would help me out a lot to get a second opinion. Thank you!

Q: Suppose $A \subset B$. Show that $B^c \subset A^c$.

Ans:
If $x\in B^c$, and $x\in A$,

Then $x\in B$, and $x\in B\Rightarrow \Leftarrow x\in B^c$

$\therefore x\in A^c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a good answer. It could be improved by specifying where the hypothesis $A \subset B$ is used.

Answer (score 2):

$A \subset B \implies (x \in A \implies x\in B)$

$\implies (x \notin B \implies x \notin A)$

$\implies (x \in B^c \implies x \in A^c)$

$\implies B^c \subset A^c$ QED

The reason for the first line is the definition of subset.  The reason for the second line is the  contrapositive law of logic.  The reason for the third line is the definition of complement. The reason for the fourth line is the definition of subset.